# Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.view.View' to 'org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView'

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv

Sorry for my bad English.
I just trying to use JavaCameraView in Android Studio like in tutorials I have been watched, but there is an error like:
"Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.view.View' to 'org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView'"
Code using JavaCameraView:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.CameraView);
}
```

XML-file:

```
<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:id="@+id/CameraView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, can you specify what tutorial you are following? It is probably a class confusion error, as it is giving you problem swith casting. You should probably be using another kind of class or widget

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to create an object of ***CameraBridgeViewBase*** to access the ***JavaCameraView*** from the xml layout.
You can refer this blog [here](https://blog.codeonion.com/2016/04/09/show-camera-on-android-app-using-opencv-for-android/) or you can check this [project](https://github.com/vulovicv23/opencv-documentscanner-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/prisca/ctest/OpenCvCamera.java) for a better insight.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have checked the blog that you attached above, but even with code copied from there i have the same problem. Also there is an error with "setVisibility" method.